# Не работает slick в модальном окне

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

Если инициализировать сначала `slick` а потом модальное окно - не работает `slick`, а если наоборот сначала инициализировать модальное окно - `slick` работает криво.

```js
//-------MODAL------
$("#faq").iziModal({
  width: 755,
  radius: 12,
  overlayColor: 'rgba(2, 7, 14, .8)',
  closeButton: true
})

//FAQ SLIDER
$(".js-faq-slider-product").slick({
  arrows: true,
  dots: true


});
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.modal {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 57px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  box-shadow: 0 4px 57px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  background-color: #02070e;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(#fdfdfd), to(#dce7ee));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #fdfdfd 0%, #dce7ee 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #fdfdfd 0%, #dce7ee 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #fdfdfd 0%, #dce7ee 100%);
  color: #4e7185;
  font-size: 1.13rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-weight: 400;
}

.modal p {
  margin-bottom: 1.8rem;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

.modal__close {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1.4rem;
  top: .8rem;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
}

.modal__close:before,
.modal__close:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 4px;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #dce7ee;
  width: 12px;
  height: 1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.modal__close:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(46deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(46deg);
  transform: rotate(46deg);
}

.modal__close:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-46deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-46deg);
  transform: rotate(-46deg);
}

.modal__caption {
  display: none;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 0 0 1.6rem;
}

.modal__caption__center {
  text-align: center;
}

.modal__row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.modal__item__sm {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 38%;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 38%;
  flex: 0 0 38%;
  max-width: 38%;
  padding-left: 2.7rem;
  padding-right: 2.1rem;
}

.modal__item__lg {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 62%;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 62%;
  flex: 0 0 62%;
  max-width: 62%;
}

.modal__item__white {
  padding-top: 5.3rem;
  padding-bottom: 5.3rem;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.modal__item__center {
  -webkit-align-self: center;
  -ms-flex-item-align: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.modal__content {
  padding-top: 10rem;
  padding-bottom: 5.3rem;
  padding-left: 5.5rem;
  padding-right: 5.5rem;
}

.modal__footer {
  background-color: #dce7ed;
  padding: 3rem 0 2rem;
}

.modal-sidebar__link {
  color: #4e7185;
}

.modal-sidebar__item {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 2.1rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

.modal-sidebar__item:before,
.modal-sidebar__item:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -2px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  display: none;
}

.modal-sidebar__item:before {
  top: .5rem;
  border-width: 0 .3rem .32rem .3rem;
  border-color: transparent transparent #4e7185 transparent;
}

.modal-sidebar__item:after {
  top: .8rem;
  border-width: .3rem .32rem 0 .3rem;
  border-color: #4e7185 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.modal-sidebar__item:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.modal-sidebar__item__active {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.modal-sidebar__item__active:before,
.modal-sidebar__item__active:after {
  display: block;
}

.modal-sidebar__item__active .modal-sidebar__link {
  color: #4e7185;
}

.modal-nav {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.modal-nav__link {
  color: #4e7185;
}

.modal-nav__item {
  padding: 0 4rem;
  position: relative;
}

.modal-nav__item:before,
.modal-nav__item:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  display: none;
}

.modal-nav__item:before {
  top: -0.9rem;
  border-width: 0 .3rem .32rem .3rem;
  border-color: transparent transparent #4e7185 transparent;
}

.modal-nav__item:after {
  top: -0.6rem;
  border-width: .3rem .32rem 0 .3rem;
  border-color: #4e7185 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.modal-nav__item:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.modal-nav__item__active {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.modal-nav__item__active:before,
.modal-nav__item__active:after {
  display: block;
}

.modal-nav__item__active .modal-nav__link {
  color: #4e7185;
}

.navigation-panel {
  display: none;
  padding: 0 1.2rem;
}

.navigation-panel__body {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #f6f9fa;
  padding: .6rem .6rem .6rem 3.4rem;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1.7rem;
  border-radius: 1.7rem;
}

.navigation-panel__dots {
  max-width: 90%;
}

.navigation-panel__more-btn {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 3.6rem;
  height: 2.2rem;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1.7rem;
  border-radius: 1.7rem;
}

.navigation-panel__more-btn svg {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -0.45rem);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -0.45rem);
  transform: translate(0, -0.45rem);
  color: #c2dae8;
  font-size: 3.2rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.faq-dots .slick-dots {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.faq-dots .slick-dots li {
  line-height: 0;
  margin-right: 2.8rem;
}

.faq-dots .slick-dots li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.faq-dots .slick-dots li button {
  font-size: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid 2px #c2dae8;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.faq-dots .slick-dots li.slick-active button {
  background-color: #c2dae8;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .navigation-panel {
    display: block;
  }
  .faq-list {
    display: none;
  }
  .modal {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 !important;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    height: 100% !important;
  }
  .modal__inside-wrap {
    padding-top: 5.5rem;
  }
  .modal__caption {
    display: block;
  }
  .modal__close {
    right: .7rem;
    top: 2.7rem;
  }
  .modal__item__sm {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 100%;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-left: 2.7rem;
    padding-right: 2.1rem;
  }
  .modal__item__lg {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 100%;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .modal__item__white {
    padding: 2.5rem;
  }
  .modal__content {
    padding: 2.5rem;
  }
  .modal__footer {
    padding: 2rem 0 2rem;
  }
  .modal-nav__item {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    padding: 0 1rem;
  }
  .modal-nav__item__active:before,
  .modal-nav__item__active:after {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/izimodal/1.5.1/css/iziModal.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/izimodal/1.5.1/js/iziModal.min.js"></script>

<!--FAQ-->
<a href="#faq" data-izimodal-open="#faq" data-izimodal-transitionin="fadeInDown" class="trigger">FAQ</a>

<div id="faq" class="modal">
  <button data-izimodal-close="" class="modal__close" style=""></button>
  <div class="modal__item modal__item__lg modal__item__center js-faq-slider-product">

    <div class="modal__content faq-content">

      <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content
        here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
        Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>

    </div>
    <div class="modal__content faq-content">

      <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content
        here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
        Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>

    </div>
    <div class="modal__content faq-content">

      <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content
        here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
        Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>

    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Что значит "работает криво"? В вашем примере слайдер одинаково работает в модальном окне и вне его.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko в модальном окне слайдер открывается вот так http://prntscr.com/lfbsww, и становится нормально после переключения слайда

Comment: Ну он точно также выглядит и вне модального окна. Уточните проблему пожалуйста, в чем вы ее видите конкретно?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko если убрать код http://prntscr.com/lfbvkz, то слайдер работает нормально! http://prntscr.com/lfbvce

Comment: Пожалуйста, общайтесь словами, а не картинками. Только у вас в голове есть сейчас понятия **нормально** или **работает криво**. Мы этих знаний не имеем. Поэтому, описывайте словами, что не работает.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Чтобы было понятно, я вам прилагаю скрины.
В модальном окне слайдер сначала сжат по ширине, и только после переключения слайда станет во всю ширину окна. Нужно чтобы при открытии модального окна слайдер был во всю ширину окна

Comment: Ну вот, с текстовым описанием стало понятнее, спасибо.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Вам спасибо! Могли бы вы помочь с еще одним вопросом?

[ссылка](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/902981/slick-%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B5-dots)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробую угадать, что вас не устраивает переносы строк в первом слайде при первом открытии модального окна.

Если так, то можно инициализировать слайдер только после того, как модальное окно откроется.

```js
//-------MODAL------
$("#faq").iziModal({
  width: 755,
  radius: 12,
  overlayColor: 'rgba(2, 7, 14, .8)',
  closeButton: true,
  onOpened: function() {
    if (!$(".js-faq-slider-product").hasClass('slick-initialized')) {
      $(".js-faq-slider-product").slick({
        arrows: true,
        dots: true
      });
    }
  }
})
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

.modal {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 4px 57px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  box-shadow: 0 4px 57px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  background-color: #02070e;
  background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, left bottom, left top, from(#fdfdfd), to(#dce7ee));
  background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(bottom, #fdfdfd 0%, #dce7ee 100%);
  background-image: -o-linear-gradient(bottom, #fdfdfd 0%, #dce7ee 100%);
  background-image: linear-gradient(to top, #fdfdfd 0%, #dce7ee 100%);
  color: #4e7185;
  font-size: 1.13rem;
  overflow: hidden;
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-weight: 400;
}

.modal p {
  margin-bottom: 1.8rem;
  line-height: 1.6;
}

.modal__close {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  position: absolute;
  right: 1.4rem;
  top: .8rem;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
}

.modal__close:before,
.modal__close:after {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  left: 4px;
  right: 0;
  background-color: #dce7ee;
  width: 12px;
  height: 1px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
  border-radius: 2px;
}

.modal__close:before {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(46deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(46deg);
  transform: rotate(46deg);
}

.modal__close:after {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-46deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-46deg);
  transform: rotate(-46deg);
}

.modal__caption {
  display: none;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  margin: 0 0 1.6rem;
}

.modal__caption__center {
  text-align: center;
}

.modal__row {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.modal__item__sm {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 38%;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 38%;
  flex: 0 0 38%;
  max-width: 38%;
  padding-left: 2.7rem;
  padding-right: 2.1rem;
}

.modal__item__lg {
  -webkit-box-flex: 0;
  -webkit-flex: 0 0 62%;
  -ms-flex: 0 0 62%;
  flex: 0 0 62%;
  max-width: 62%;
}

.modal__item__white {
  padding-top: 5.3rem;
  padding-bottom: 5.3rem;
  background-color: #ffffff;
}

.modal__item__center {
  -webkit-align-self: center;
  -ms-flex-item-align: center;
  align-self: center;
}

.modal__content {
  padding-top: 10rem;
  padding-bottom: 5.3rem;
  padding-left: 5.5rem;
  padding-right: 5.5rem;
}

.modal__footer {
  background-color: #dce7ed;
  padding: 3rem 0 2rem;
}

.modal-sidebar__link {
  color: #4e7185;
}

.modal-sidebar__item {
  position: relative;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  margin-bottom: 2.1rem;
  padding-left: 1rem;
}

.modal-sidebar__item:before,
.modal-sidebar__item:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: -2px;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  display: none;
}

.modal-sidebar__item:before {
  top: .5rem;
  border-width: 0 .3rem .32rem .3rem;
  border-color: transparent transparent #4e7185 transparent;
}

.modal-sidebar__item:after {
  top: .8rem;
  border-width: .3rem .32rem 0 .3rem;
  border-color: #4e7185 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.modal-sidebar__item:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.modal-sidebar__item__active {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.modal-sidebar__item__active:before,
.modal-sidebar__item__active:after {
  display: block;
}

.modal-sidebar__item__active .modal-sidebar__link {
  color: #4e7185;
}

.modal-nav {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-flex-wrap: wrap;
  -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.modal-nav__link {
  color: #4e7185;
}

.modal-nav__item {
  padding: 0 4rem;
  position: relative;
}

.modal-nav__item:before,
.modal-nav__item:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-style: solid;
  display: none;
}

.modal-nav__item:before {
  top: -0.9rem;
  border-width: 0 .3rem .32rem .3rem;
  border-color: transparent transparent #4e7185 transparent;
}

.modal-nav__item:after {
  top: -0.6rem;
  border-width: .3rem .32rem 0 .3rem;
  border-color: #4e7185 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.modal-nav__item:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}

.modal-nav__item__active {
  font-weight: 500;
}

.modal-nav__item__active:before,
.modal-nav__item__active:after {
  display: block;
}

.modal-nav__item__active .modal-nav__link {
  color: #4e7185;
}

.navigation-panel {
  display: none;
  padding: 0 1.2rem;
}

.navigation-panel__body {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: justify;
  -webkit-justify-content: space-between;
  -ms-flex-pack: justify;
  justify-content: space-between;
  background-color: #f6f9fa;
  padding: .6rem .6rem .6rem 3.4rem;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1.7rem;
  border-radius: 1.7rem;
}

.navigation-panel__dots {
  max-width: 90%;
}

.navigation-panel__more-btn {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
  -webkit-justify-content: center;
  -ms-flex-pack: center;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 3.6rem;
  height: 2.2rem;
  background-color: #ffffff;
  -webkit-border-radius: 1.7rem;
  border-radius: 1.7rem;
}

.navigation-panel__more-btn svg {
  -webkit-transform: translate(0, -0.45rem);
  -ms-transform: translate(0, -0.45rem);
  transform: translate(0, -0.45rem);
  color: #c2dae8;
  font-size: 3.2rem;
  width: 100%;
}

.faq-dots .slick-dots {
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -webkit-flex;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
  -webkit-align-items: center;
  -ms-flex-align: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.faq-dots .slick-dots li {
  line-height: 0;
  margin-right: 2.8rem;
}

.faq-dots .slick-dots li:last-child {
  margin-right: 0;
}

.faq-dots .slick-dots li button {
  font-size: 0;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  border: solid 2px #c2dae8;
  -webkit-border-radius: 50%;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: transparent;
}

.faq-dots .slick-dots li.slick-active button {
  background-color: #c2dae8;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  .navigation-panel {
    display: block;
  }
  .faq-list {
    display: none;
  }
  .modal {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 !important;
    border-radius: 0 !important;
    height: 100% !important;
  }
  .modal__inside-wrap {
    padding-top: 5.5rem;
  }
  .modal__caption {
    display: block;
  }
  .modal__close {
    right: .7rem;
    top: 2.7rem;
  }
  .modal__item__sm {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 100%;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    padding-left: 2.7rem;
    padding-right: 2.1rem;
  }
  .modal__item__lg {
    -webkit-box-flex: 0;
    -webkit-flex: 0 0 100%;
    -ms-flex: 0 0 100%;
    flex: 0 0 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
  .modal__item__white {
    padding: 2.5rem;
  }
  .modal__content {
    padding: 2.5rem;
  }
  .modal__footer {
    padding: 2rem 0 2rem;
  }
  .modal-nav__item {
    font-size: 1.6rem;
    padding: 0 1rem;
  }
  .modal-nav__item__active:before,
  .modal-nav__item__active:after {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/izimodal/1.5.1/css/iziModal.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.9.0/slick.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/izimodal/1.5.1/js/iziModal.min.js"></script>

<!--FAQ-->
<a href="#faq" data-izimodal-open="#faq" data-izimodal-transitionin="fadeInDown" class="trigger">FAQ</a>

<div id="faq" class="modal">
  <button data-izimodal-close="" class="modal__close" style=""></button>
  <div class="modal__item modal__item__lg modal__item__center">

    <div class="modal__content faq-content">

      <div class="js-faq-slider-product">

        <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content
          here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
          Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>

        <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content
          here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
          Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>

        <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content
          here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
          Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>

      </div>

    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```